# Cannot Retrieve data from database With php MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I want to retrieve some Data from database using custom PHP MVC.

I created a **Controller** File

**semestres.php**

```
class Semestres extends Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();      
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->view->fetchSemestres = $this->model->fetchSemestres();
        $this->view->render('semestres/index');
    }
}
```

a **Model**

**semestres_model.php**

```
class Semestres_Model extends Model{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fetchSemestres(){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM semestres");  
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();       
    }   
}
```

and a **View** file  **index** inside the folder **semestre**.

```
foreach($this->fetchSemestres AS $key=>$value){
    echo $value['intitule_semestre']."<br>";
}
```

But it gives me nothing !!!

The print_r($this->fetchSemestres) gives me an empty array

> Array ( )

**// Update:**

**Database connection:**

```
class Database extends PDO{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('mysql:host:localhost;dbname:planingexams', 'root', '');
    }
}
```

**Model.php**

```
class Model{

    function __construct(){
        $this->db =  new Database();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code above and added database connection

Comment: That Array() is the result of your echo? 
if so try a var_dump instead of an echo. The act that you get array() means $value['intitule_semestre'] contains an array and echo cannot print what is inside.

Comment: it the  result of print_();

Comment: pint_r($this->fetchSemestres);

Comment: the foreach loop gives me nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class Database extends PDO{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=planingexams', 'root', '');
    }
}
```

I tested your code locally and added

```
var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
```

This gave me:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1] =>
  int(1046)
  [2] =>
  string(20) "No database selected"
}
```

So after taking a good look at the database connection it seems you had to use = and not : to assign the values.

See:

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$db;user=$user;password=$pass");
```

From

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php